# Heroku - Clojure - Connecting to a re-frame application

Tags: heroku, clojure

I have a clojure app running on a heroku dyno with a postgresql database. How would I go about connecting this database to a reframe application.

I understand that I can use REST services such as compojure to do my routing but I am confused as to how to connect the application to that specific database. Do I just give it the same location?

Also does my reframe app have to be on the Heroku dyno in order to connect to the postgres database on there as the database is set as an env?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

re-frame isn't connected to postgresql, but manages the state of the application on the client side.  You would connect re-frame to the server some other way such as http (REST services) or websockets.  I recommend [luminus](http://www.luminusweb.net/) to get started with clojure web app dev.  re-frame and postgresql are some of the available options for initial generation.  I also recommend Dmitri's book about clojure web app development called [Web Development with Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/dswdcloj2/web-development-with-clojure-second-edition).  [re-frame docs](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/tree/master/docs) are good too.